# UWP pass informations between applications

Tags: c#, uwp

I use FullTrustProcessLauncher to launch another app which is a console application from my UWP application and I want to pass informations/parameters between these two apps.

Maybe I have to use SharedMemory or something like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Marian Dolinsky, I continued my researches in the right way and I have found a sample developped by Microsoft. It shows how to communicate between UWP app and console application (it is the same thing if you want to communicate with WPF or Win Forms app) using AppService APIs. The link to the github : [Sample Microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServiceBridgeSample/cs)

Comment: Please mark this answer as the one that resolved your issue - may help other users with similar problems.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [UWP's built-in mechanism](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/05/24/sharing-your-local-app-data/#Pkk1ZUqJzOPY8lqI.97) to share local data between apps or if you just need to pass some data on startup you should use the [Protocol activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation) as Vijay Nirmal said.

Comment: Is the App-to-app communication only allow communcation between two UWP apps ?

Comment: It can't work with a Console Application because I have to copy that in a manifest `<Extensions>
  <Extension Category="windows.publisherCacheFolders">
    <PublisherCacheFolders>
      <Folder Name="Downloads" />
    </PublisherCacheFolders>
  </Extension>
</Extensions>`

Comment: So you're launching Win32 app, not converted using Desktop App Converter from your UWP app?

Comment: I launch a console application from my UWP app using FullTrustProcessLauncher.
No, I don't use Desktop App Converter, should I use it ?

Comment: I was just asking, it depends, but it would enable to use some UWP APIs in it.

Comment: I have found a solution, thank you for your help it was very helpful. My answer explains how I have resolved the problem.